# search and replace a string in cell

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, numpy

I have row value of a voltage measurement.

```
-Infinity,
0.00061050,
0.00061050,
-Infinity,
0.00061050,
-Infinity,
-Infinity,
0.00061050,
0.00122100,
Infinity,
Infinity,
Infinity,
Infinity,
```

I only need the "Infinity" replaced with 1

actually numpy converts `"+/-Infinity"` to `-inf` or `inf`

```
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
> import numpy as np
> 
> x, y, z =
> np.loadtxt('20180618-0001_innen_aussen_innen_0_25_Sek_Abtast.csv',
> delimiter=',', skiprows=10, unpack=True)

> 
> z[z == '-inf'] = 1
> 
> print(z) plt.plot(x,y,z, label='Loaded from file!')        
>
> plt.xlabel('x')
>
> plt.ylabel('y')
>
> plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')
>
> plt.legend() 
>
> plt.show()
```

Comment: @Kasramvd, thanks for editing

Comment: Have you tried using `.replace('old_value', 'new value')`?

Comment: Don't use replace, use array masking. Btw.: `replace` is from `pandas` and not `numpy`.

Comment: Why did you unmark my answer? It is correct and it works. It seems to be an error with your data that causes your trouble with positive `np.inf`. Anyways I added another explanation to my answer. Try this to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a boolean mask to index the array and apply the operation (setting the masked values to 1):

```
z[np.abs(z) == np.inf] = 1
```

Thanks at SashaTsukanov for pointing out that you can also use:

```
z[np.isinf(z)] = 1
```

If you want to set separate values to your `z` array depending on positive or negative `np.inf`:

```
# create some random test data:
z = np.random.rand(10)
z[4] = -np.inf
z[8] = np.inf
# apply it:
z[z == -np.inf] = 0
z[z == np.inf] = 1
print(z)  # print it
# out: [0.15883998, 0.16284797, 0.3730809, 0.37536173, 0., 0.41195883, 0.39620129, 0.74374664, 1., 0.87745629]
```

If this does not work in your case for positive `np.inf`, try the following:

```
z[z == -np.inf] = 0
z[np.isinf(z)] = 1
```

Comment: Or use `np.isinf`

Comment: @SashaTsukanov yeah, you are right. This would be the most straight-forward solution. I added it to my answer. Mine can be used in all comparisons, thus I also left it in the answer.

Comment: @Scotty1- That's not what mask means. What you are doing is 'indexing' or creating a 'view' https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#what-is-a-masked-array

Comment: @FHTMitchell You are right that it is not a masked array in the meaning of the `numpy.ma` module, but still I am creating a temporary boolean mask to index the array. Masking just refers to the general way of creating an index array of *the same shape as the array to be indexed* which shouldn't be confused with the term *masked array*, which is in fact a special numpy array subclass.

Comment: Literally never heard that term used in the numpy community but it seems you aren't wrong. We just tend to call them boolean arrays / boolean index arrays.

Comment: @FHTMitchell Yeah, I guess *masking* is a more general and not numpy-specific term.

Answer (score 0):

only `-inf` is affected

with `z[ ==np.inf] = 1` don't do to `inf` at all

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y, z = np.loadtxt('20180618-0001_innen_aussen_innen_0_25_Sek_Abtast.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=10, unpack=True)




z[z == np.inf] = 1
z[z == -np.inf]= 0


for row in z:
    print(row)
```